# Android app unable to communicate over the network

Tags: android, android-networking

I am running into a bizarre problem on some of our customers' phones.  It seems, that after being outside of a service area for a number of hours my Android app would lose ability to access the network.  Other applications such as web browser or e-mail would be able to access the web, but not my app.

The only conceivable explanation is that it is somehow leaking sockets when there is no data service.

Here is my code:

```
String sendWebPOST(String url, String pPostData) throws IOException {
    AndroidHttpClient c = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    OutputStream os = null;
    int rc;
    String strResponse = null;

    try {            
        c = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Mobile");

        // Set the request method and headers
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
        request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        request.setEntity(new StringEntity(pPostData));

        try {
            HttpResponse response = c.execute(request);

            // Getting the response code will open the connection,
            // send the request, and read the HTTP response headers.
            // The headers are stored until requested.
            rc = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (rc != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                throw new IOException("HTTP response code: " + rc);
            }

            try {
                is = response.getEntity().getContent();

                int ch;
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                while ((ch = is.read()) != -1) {
                    sb.append((char) ch);
                }
                //if(sb.length() > 0)
                strResponse = sb.toString();
            }
            finally {
                if (is != null) {
                    is.close();
                }
            }
        }
        finally {
            if (os != null) {
                os.close();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not an HTTP URL");
    }
    finally {
        if (c != null) {
            c.close();
        }
    }

    return strResponse;
}
```

This function is called about once every ten minutes to send an update to a remote server.  When the app gets into this weird state the user is still able to open the activities, interact with menus, etc. so the app is still running.  However, it is not able to send anything through the network.

Any ideas what may be going on?

The phones in question are myTouch 4G and Samsung Galaxy II running Android 2.3 on T-Mobile network.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, using HttpURLConnection instead of AndroidHttpClient woks better.  Once I upgraded my code I don't get any more problems reported.

```
 HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    OutputStream os = null;
    String strResponse = null;

    try {
        conn = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL(url)).openConnection();

        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
        conn.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
        conn.connect();

        os = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

        os.write(pPostData.getBytes());
        os.flush();

        // Getting the response code will open the connection,
        // send the request, and read the HTTP response headers.
        // The headers are stored until requested.
        int rc = conn.getResponseCode();
        if (rc != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            throw new IOException("HTTP response code: " + rc);
        }

        is = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());

        int ch;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while ((ch = is.read()) != -1) {
            sb.append((char) ch);
        }
        //if(sb.length() > 0)
        strResponse = sb.toString();
    }
    finally {

        if (is != null) {
            try {
                is.close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("is.close ex " + ex);
            }
        }
        if (os != null) {
            try {
                os.close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("os.close ex " + ex);
            }
        }

        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("disconnect ex " + ex);
            }
        }
    }
```